# How to redirect to requested URL after login (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have a question about routing with React.

My goal

In a normal login, I use `dispatch(push('/'))`  and the user jumps to the Home after log　in, but I want the user to be redirected to the requested page (add info page in this repo) when log in from a link in the email sent to the user.(The URL have a token)

e.g. This link will be emailed. https://localhost/add-info/*token*

When the user presses the above link in the email, the user will be redirected to the login page and After logging in, I want the user to go to the information registration page instead of the home page.

I want to implement this, but I don't know how. Can someone please tell me how to do this?

Comment: Do you have a add-info page on Front-end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add a query within the link provided to the user's mail, and then search for URL query every time a user enters the login page (in your login page backend code). [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript) is how you read URL queries with JS...

Then provide a conditional dispatch in the end of the login algorithm for redirecting. like this:

```
if (url.query.redirectURL)
    dispatch(push('/' + url.query.redirectURL))
```

This is actually the concept...

Comment: Thank you very much! You mean the url shoud have query like this?  ```https://localhost/add-info ``` and no need to have user token?

Comment: Shape the data given in the url as you desire. Usually query comes like this: `https://your.domain.com/page?query1=data_you_chose&query2=data_you_chose` and your code then can read `query1` or `query2` when the browser gets to those pages.